# Splitting multiple columns using mutate - dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to split multiple columns, but struggling to do this efficiently.

I have a df:

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID = c("DIS-1101-1001-E1", "DIS-1101-1002-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1003-E1", "DIS-1101-1004-E1", "DIS-1101-1004-E2", "DIS-1101-1005-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1006-E1", "DIS-1101-1007-E1", "DIS-1101-1008-E1", "DIS-1101-1009-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1010-E1", "DIS-1101-1011-E1", "DIS-1101-1012-E1", "DIS-1101-1013-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1014-E1", "DIS-1101-1015-E1", "DIS-1101-1016-E1", "DIS-1101-1017-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1018-E1", "DIS-1101-1019-E1", "DIS-1101-1020-E1", "DIS-1101-1021-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1022-E1", "DIS-1101-1023-E1", "DIS-1101-1025-E1", "DIS-1101-1026-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1027-E1", "DIS-1101-1028-E1", "DIS-1101-1029-E1", "DIS-1101-1030-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1031-E1", "DIS-1101-1032-E1", "DIS-1101-1033-E1", "DIS-1101-1034-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1035-E1", "DIS-1101-1036-E1", "DIS-1101-1037-E1", "DIS-1101-1038-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1039-E1", "DIS-1101-1040-E1", "DIS-1101-1041-E1", "DIS-1101-1042-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1042-E2", "DIS-1101-1043-E1", "DIS-1101-1044-E1", "DIS-1101-1045-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1046-E1", "DIS-1101-1047-E1", "DIS-1101-1048-E1", "DIS-1101-1049-E1"
), `TIME_POINT_1=HAEMOGLOBIN` = c("BASELINE=123.00;FIRST=117.00", 
"FIRST=92.00", "FIRST=111.00", "BASELINE=125.00;FIRST=113.00", 
"FIRST=124.00", "NULL=NULL", "NULL=NULL", "FIRST=77.00", "FIRST=132.00", 
"FIRST=123.00", "BASELINE=119.00;FIRST=93.00", "BASELINE=163.00;FIRST=141.00", 
"FIRST=137.00", "NULL=NULL", "NULL=NULL", "FIRST=137.00", "FIRST=127.00", 
"BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=101.00;SECOND=105.00", "FIRST=120.00", "FIRST=145.00", 
"FIRST=126.00", "BASELINE=93.00;FIRST=82.00", "BASELINE=114.00;FIRST=95.00", 
"BASELINE=137.00;FIRST=125.00", "BASELINE=157.00;FIRST=112.00", 
"NULL=NULL", "FIRST=127.00", "FIRST=147.00", "BASELINE=80.00;FIRST=92.00", 
"BASELINE=129.00;FIRST=131.00", "FIRST=108.00", "BASELINE=92.00;FIRST=80.00", 
"BASELINE=118.00;FIRST=107.00", "NULL=NULL", "NULL=NULL", "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=89.00", 
"NULL=NULL", "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=101.00", "FIRST=151.00", "FIRST=106.00", 
"BASELINE=81.00;FIRST=87.00", "FIRST=94.00;SECOND=85.00", "FIRST=85.00", 
"FIRST=118.00;SECOND=116.00", "FIRST=101.00;SECOND=103.00", "FIRST=114.00", 
"BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=129.00", "BASELINE=123.00;FIRST=105.00", 
"NULL=NULL", "NULL=NULL"), `TIME_POINT_2=WHITE_CELLS` = c("BASELINE=2.90;FIRST=2.40", 
"FIRST=14.80", "FIRST=11.00", "BASELINE=6.90;FIRST=7.30", "FIRST=4.50", 
"NULL=NULL", "NULL=NULL", "FIRST=6.10", "FIRST=7.70", "FIRST=16.20", 
"BASELINE=7.40;FIRST=5.30", "BASELINE=12.80;FIRST=10.30", "FIRST=14.50", 
"NULL=NULL", "NULL=NULL", "FIRST=12.80", "FIRST=3.70", "BASELINE=4.20;FIRST=4.70;SECOND=6.50", 
"FIRST=16.60", "FIRST=9.30", "FIRST=15.90", "BASELINE=31.00;FIRST=31.70", 
"BASELINE=3.70;FIRST=7.00", "BASELINE=14.10;FIRST=7.20", "BASELINE=21.80;FIRST=31.20", 
"NULL=NULL", "FIRST=9.20", "FIRST=5.90", "BASELINE=2.20;FIRST=0.50", 
"BASELINE=10.50;FIRST=10.60", "FIRST=12.00", "BASELINE=14.70;FIRST=11.80", 
"BASELINE=13.40;FIRST=13.00", "NULL=NULL", "NULL=NULL", "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=18.60", 
"NULL=NULL", "BASELINE=4.30;FIRST=5.90", "FIRST=7.60", "FIRST=3.10", 
"BASELINE=10.10;FIRST=11.40", "FIRST=12.00;SECOND=21.30", "FIRST=9.80", 
"FIRST=29.50;SECOND=4.80", "FIRST=4.60;SECOND=9.90", "FIRST=18.90", 
"BASELINE=15.00;FIRST=13.00", "BASELINE=12.80;FIRST=10.60", "NULL=NULL", 
"NULL=NULL")), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I want this output:

```
dput(output)
structure(list(UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID = c("DIS-1101-1001-E1", "DIS-1101-1002-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1003-E1", "DIS-1101-1004-E1", "DIS-1101-1004-E2", "DIS-1101-1005-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1006-E1", "DIS-1101-1007-E1", "DIS-1101-1008-E1", "DIS-1101-1009-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1010-E1", "DIS-1101-1011-E1", "DIS-1101-1012-E1", "DIS-1101-1013-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1014-E1", "DIS-1101-1015-E1", "DIS-1101-1016-E1", "DIS-1101-1017-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1018-E1", "DIS-1101-1019-E1", "DIS-1101-1020-E1", "DIS-1101-1021-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1022-E1", "DIS-1101-1023-E1", "DIS-1101-1025-E1", "DIS-1101-1026-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1027-E1", "DIS-1101-1028-E1", "DIS-1101-1029-E1", "DIS-1101-1030-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1031-E1", "DIS-1101-1032-E1", "DIS-1101-1033-E1", "DIS-1101-1034-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1035-E1", "DIS-1101-1036-E1", "DIS-1101-1037-E1", "DIS-1101-1038-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1039-E1", "DIS-1101-1040-E1", "DIS-1101-1041-E1", "DIS-1101-1042-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1042-E2", "DIS-1101-1043-E1", "DIS-1101-1044-E1", "DIS-1101-1045-E1", 
"DIS-1101-1046-E1", "DIS-1101-1047-E1", "DIS-1101-1048-E1", "DIS-1101-1049-E1"
), Haemoglobin_BASELINE = c("123.00", NA, NA, "125.00", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "119.00", "163.00", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "NULL", 
NA, NA, NA, "93.00", "114.00", "137.00", "157.00", NA, NA, NA, 
"80.00", "129.00", NA, "92.00", "118.00", NA, NA, "NULL", NA, 
"NULL", NA, NA, "81.00", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "NULL", "123.00", 
NA, NA), Haemoglobin_FIRST = c("117.00", "92.00", "111.00", "113.00", 
"124.00", NA, NA, "77.00", "132.00", "123.00", "93.00", "141.00", 
"137.00", NA, NA, "137.00", "127.00", "101.00", "120.00", "145.00", 
"126.00", "82.00", "95.00", "125.00", "112.00", NA, "127.00", 
"147.00", "92.00", "131.00", "108.00", "80.00", "107.00", NA, 
NA, "89.00", NA, "101.00", "151.00", "106.00", "87.00", "94.00", 
"85.00", "118.00", "101.00", "114.00", "129.00", "105.00", NA, 
NA), Haemoglobin_SECOND = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "105.00", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "85.00", NA, "116.00", "103.00", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    WBC_BASELINE = c("2.90", NA, NA, "6.90", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, "7.40", "12.80", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "4.20", NA, 
    NA, NA, "31.00", "3.70", "14.10", "21.80", NA, NA, NA, "2.20", 
    "10.50", NA, "14.70", "13.40", NA, NA, "NULL", NA, "4.30", 
    NA, NA, "10.10", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "15.00", "12.80", NA, 
    NA), WBC_FIRST = c("2.40", "14.80", "11.00", "7.30", "4.50", 
    NA, NA, "6.10", "7.70", "16.20", "5.30", "10.30", "14.50", 
    NA, NA, "12.80", "3.70", "4.70", "16.60", "9.30", "15.90", 
    "31.70", "7.00", "7.20", "31.20", NA, "9.20", "5.90", "0.50", 
    "10.60", "12.00", "11.80", "13.00", NA, NA, "18.60", NA, 
    "5.90", "7.60", "3.10", "11.40", "12.00", "9.80", "29.50", 
    "4.60", "18.90", "13.00", "10.60", NA, NA), WBC_SECOND = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "6.50", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "21.30", NA, 
    "4.80", "9.90", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -50L
), class = "data.frame")
```

I can achieve this, but my code is inefficient (as I am doing this on each blood column):

```
#haemoglobin
haem_ID <- df %>% select(UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID, `TIME_POINT_1=HAEMOGLOBIN`)

haem_sep <- haem_ID %>%
  rename(text = `TIME_POINT_1=HAEMOGLOBIN`) %>%
  separate_rows(text, sep = ';') %>%
  separate(text, c('text', 'value'), sep = '=') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = text, values_from = value)

tmp <- haem_sep %>% select(-UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID)
colnames(tmp) <- paste("Haemoglobin", colnames(tmp), sep = "_")
tmp2 <- haem_ID %>% select(UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID)
cbind(tmp2, tmp) -> tmp3
tmp3 %<>% select(-Haemoglobin_NULL)
haem <- tmp3


#white cells
a <- df %>% select(UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID, `TIME_POINT_2=WHITE_CELLS`)

b <- a %>%
  rename(text = `TIME_POINT_2=WHITE_CELLS`) %>%
  separate_rows(text, sep = ';') %>%
  separate(text, c('text', 'value'), sep = '=') %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = text, values_from = value)

tmp <- b %>% select(-UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID)
colnames(tmp) <- paste("WBC", colnames(tmp), sep = "_")
tmp2 <- a %>% select(UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID)
cbind(tmp2, tmp) -> tmp3
tmp3 %<>% select(-WBC_NULL)
WBC <- tmp3

output <- merge(haem, WBC)
```

Pls can someone help me achieve the same but more effectively please? In reality I have 20 blood tests and not just 2, so hard-coding it is not ideal.

****UPDATE****

Upon the kind responses, I've tried running the suggested code but I'm getting an error and I can't figure out why.

input data

```
structure(list(UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID = c("DIS-1104-1021-E1", "DIS-1107-1010-E1", 
"DIS-1124-1108-E1"), `TIME_POINT_1=HAEMOGLOBIN` = c("BASELINE=98.00;FIRST=90.00;SECOND=81.00;FIRST=85.00", 
"FIRST=120.00;NULL=120.00;NULL=118.00;SECOND=109.00;NULL=186.00", 
"BASELINE=78.00;FIRST=NULL;FIRST=99.00"), `TIME_POINT_2=WHITE_CELLS` = c("BASELINE=0.01;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=0.01;FIRST=0.00", 
"FIRST=15.40;NULL=16.10;NULL=14.50;SECOND=11.40;NULL=2.20;NULL=5.00", 
"BASELINE=85.00;FIRST=NULL;FIRST=209.00"), `TIME_POINT_3=PLATELETS` = c("BASELINE=28.00;FIRST=28.00;SECOND=12.00;FIRST=21.00", 
"FIRST=200.00;NULL=186.00;NULL=203.00;SECOND=243.00;NULL=145.00;NULL=457.00", 
"BASELINE=186.00;FIRST=NULL"), `TIME_POINT_4=NEUTROPHILS` = c("BASELINE=0.00;FIRST=0.00;SECOND=0.00", 
"FIRST=13.00;NULL=13.20;NULL=11.10;SECOND=7.70;NULL=1.30;NULL=2.20", 
"BASELINE=7.10;FIRST=2.40;FIRST=NULL"), `TIME_POINT_5=LYMPHOCYTES` = c("BASELINE=0.00;FIRST=0.00;SECOND=0.00", 
"FIRST=0.80;NULL=1.60;NULL=1.40;SECOND=1.70;NULL=0.40", "BASELINE=76.80;FIRST=135.00;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_6=MONOCYTES` = c("BASELINE=0.00;FIRST=0.00;SECOND=0.00", 
"FIRST=1.50;NULL=1.20;NULL=1.90;SECOND=2.00;NULL=0.40;NULL=0.90", 
"BASELINE=1.40;FIRST=4.20;FIRST=NULL"), `TIME_POINT_7=EOSINOPHILS` = c("BASELINE=0.00;FIRST=0.00;SECOND=0.00", 
"FIRST=0.10;NULL=0.00;SECOND=0.00;NULL=0.10;NULL=0.30", "BASELINE=0.10;FIRST=0.40;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_8=FIBRINOGEN` = c("BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL", 
"FIRST=6.90;NULL=6.60;NULL=7.10;SECOND=6.60;NULL=6.00;NULL=NULL", 
"BASELINE=6.70;FIRST=NULL"), `TIME_POINT_9=PT` = c("BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL", 
"FIRST=19.20;NULL=17.20;NULL=16.10;SECOND=14.40;NULL=14.90;NULL=NULL", 
"BASELINE=13.40;FIRST=NULL"), `TIME_POINT_10=UREA` = c("BASELINE=4.30;FIRST=4.30;SECOND=5.10;FIRST=4.50", 
"FIRST=3.80;NULL=3.70;NULL=4.40;SECOND=2.80;NULL=2.90;NULL=4.10", 
"BASELINE=5.10;FIRST=NULL;FIRST=7.20"), `TIME_POINT_11=CREATININE` = c("BASELINE=67.00;FIRST=55.00;SECOND=61.00;FIRST=60.00", 
"FIRST=44.00;NULL=42.00;NULL=45.00;SECOND=42.00;NULL=33.00", 
"BASELINE=65.00;FIRST=NULL;FIRST=72.00"), `TIME_POINT_12=ALT` = c("BASELINE=9.00;FIRST=11.00;SECOND=8.00;FIRST=5.00", 
"FIRST=20.00;NULL=NULL;NULL=19.00;SECOND=16.00;NULL=16.00;NULL=21.00", 
"BASELINE=64.00;FIRST=NULL;FIRST=92.00"), `TIME_POINT_13=BILIRUBIN` = c("BASELINE=3.00;FIRST=5.00;SECOND=3.00;FIRST=NULL", 
"FIRST=20.00;NULL=NULL;NULL=11.00;SECOND=10.00;NULL=5.00", "BASELINE=7.00;FIRST=NULL;FIRST=10.00"
), `TIME_POINT_14=ALBUMIN` = c("BASELINE=42.00;FIRST=39.00;SECOND=35.00;FIRST=36.00", 
"FIRST=42.00;NULL=NULL;NULL=37.00;SECOND=35.00;NULL=35.00;NULL=39.00", 
"BASELINE=31.00;FIRST=NULL;FIRST=40.00"), `TIME_POINT_15=VITAMIN_D` = c("BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL", 
"FIRST=NULL;NULL=NULL;SECOND=NULL", "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_16=CRP` = c("BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=172.00;SECOND=116.00;FIRST=212.00", 
"FIRST=427.00;NULL=420.00;NULL=338.00;SECOND=215.00;NULL=87.00;NULL=64.00", 
"BASELINE=199.00;FIRST=NULL;FIRST=1.00"), `TIME_POINT_17=PCT` = c("BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL", 
"FIRST=NULL;NULL=NULL;SECOND=NULL", "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_18=FERRITIN` = c("BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL", 
"FIRST=NULL;NULL=NULL;NULL=378.00;SECOND=NULL", "BASELINE=809.00;FIRST=432.00;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_19=TROP_T` = c("BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL", 
"FIRST=NULL;NULL=NULL;NULL=3.00;SECOND=NULL", "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_20=D_DIMER` = c("BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL", 
"FIRST=NULL;NULL=1.85;NULL=1.65;SECOND=NULL;NULL=NULL", "BASELINE=749.00;FIRST=486.00;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_21=INR` = c("BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL", 
"FIRST=NULL;NULL=NULL;SECOND=NULL", "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_22=BNP_NT` = c("BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL", 
"FIRST=NULL;NULL=NULL;SECOND=NULL", "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_23=LDH` = c("BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL", 
"FIRST=NULL;NULL=NULL;SECOND=NULL", "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=254.00;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_24=CK` = c("BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL", 
"FIRST=NULL;NULL=NULL;NULL=29.00;SECOND=NULL", "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_25=SCD_25` = c("BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL", 
"FIRST=NULL;NULL=NULL;SECOND=NULL", "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_26=BASE_EXCESS` = c("BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL", 
"FIRST=3.10;NULL=1.50;NULL=NULL;SECOND=NULL", "BASELINE=-3.80;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_27=LACTATE` = c("BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL", 
"FIRST=0.90;NULL=1.30;NULL=NULL;SECOND=NULL", "BASELINE=0.60;FIRST=NULL"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Code:

```
output <- input |> 
  separate_rows(-UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID, sep = ";") |> 
  pivot_longer(-UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID) |> 
  separate(value, into = c("timepoint", "value"), sep = "=") |> 
  mutate(name = str_remove(name, ".*=")) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c("name", "timepoint")) |> 
  select(-ends_with("NULL"))
```

Error message:

```
Error in `fn()`:
! In row 2, can't recycle input of size 5 to size 6.
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last `select` line is optional depending on how you want the columns ordered and whether or not you wish to keep the NULL columns:

```
df |> 
  separate_rows(-UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID, sep = ";") |> 
  pivot_longer(-UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID) |> 
  separate(value, into = c("timepoint", "value"), sep = "=") |> 
  mutate(name = str_remove(name, ".*=")) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c("name", "timepoint")) |> 
  select(UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID, sort(tidyselect::peek_vars()), -contains("NULL"))
```

Using the example data with syntactic columns names, i.e. using a "." instead of "="), the following reprex may be run in a clean R session:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(
  ~UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID,                  ~TIME_POINT_1.HAEMOGLOBIN,              ~TIME_POINT_2.WHITE_CELLS,
  "DIS-1101-1001-E1",             "BASELINE=123.00;FIRST=117.00",             "BASELINE=2.90;FIRST=2.40",
  "DIS-1101-1002-E1",                              "FIRST=92.00",                          "FIRST=14.80",
  "DIS-1101-1003-E1",                             "FIRST=111.00",                          "FIRST=11.00",
  "DIS-1101-1004-E1",             "BASELINE=125.00;FIRST=113.00",             "BASELINE=6.90;FIRST=7.30",
  "DIS-1101-1004-E2",                             "FIRST=124.00",                           "FIRST=4.50",
  "DIS-1101-1005-E1",                                "NULL=NULL",                            "NULL=NULL",
  "DIS-1101-1006-E1",                                "NULL=NULL",                            "NULL=NULL",
  "DIS-1101-1007-E1",                              "FIRST=77.00",                           "FIRST=6.10",
  "DIS-1101-1008-E1",                             "FIRST=132.00",                           "FIRST=7.70",
  "DIS-1101-1009-E1",                             "FIRST=123.00",                          "FIRST=16.20",
  "DIS-1101-1010-E1",              "BASELINE=119.00;FIRST=93.00",             "BASELINE=7.40;FIRST=5.30",
  "DIS-1101-1011-E1",             "BASELINE=163.00;FIRST=141.00",           "BASELINE=12.80;FIRST=10.30",
  "DIS-1101-1012-E1",                             "FIRST=137.00",                          "FIRST=14.50",
  "DIS-1101-1013-E1",                                "NULL=NULL",                            "NULL=NULL",
  "DIS-1101-1014-E1",                                "NULL=NULL",                            "NULL=NULL",
  "DIS-1101-1015-E1",                             "FIRST=137.00",                          "FIRST=12.80",
  "DIS-1101-1016-E1",                             "FIRST=127.00",                           "FIRST=3.70",
  "DIS-1101-1017-E1", "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=101.00;SECOND=105.00", "BASELINE=4.20;FIRST=4.70;SECOND=6.50",
  "DIS-1101-1018-E1",                             "FIRST=120.00",                          "FIRST=16.60",
  "DIS-1101-1019-E1",                             "FIRST=145.00",                           "FIRST=9.30",
  "DIS-1101-1020-E1",                             "FIRST=126.00",                          "FIRST=15.90",
  "DIS-1101-1021-E1",               "BASELINE=93.00;FIRST=82.00",           "BASELINE=31.00;FIRST=31.70",
  "DIS-1101-1022-E1",              "BASELINE=114.00;FIRST=95.00",             "BASELINE=3.70;FIRST=7.00",
  "DIS-1101-1023-E1",             "BASELINE=137.00;FIRST=125.00",            "BASELINE=14.10;FIRST=7.20",
  "DIS-1101-1025-E1",             "BASELINE=157.00;FIRST=112.00",           "BASELINE=21.80;FIRST=31.20",
  "DIS-1101-1026-E1",                                "NULL=NULL",                            "NULL=NULL",
  "DIS-1101-1027-E1",                             "FIRST=127.00",                           "FIRST=9.20",
  "DIS-1101-1028-E1",                             "FIRST=147.00",                           "FIRST=5.90",
  "DIS-1101-1029-E1",               "BASELINE=80.00;FIRST=92.00",             "BASELINE=2.20;FIRST=0.50",
  "DIS-1101-1030-E1",             "BASELINE=129.00;FIRST=131.00",           "BASELINE=10.50;FIRST=10.60",
  "DIS-1101-1031-E1",                             "FIRST=108.00",                          "FIRST=12.00",
  "DIS-1101-1032-E1",               "BASELINE=92.00;FIRST=80.00",           "BASELINE=14.70;FIRST=11.80",
  "DIS-1101-1033-E1",             "BASELINE=118.00;FIRST=107.00",           "BASELINE=13.40;FIRST=13.00",
  "DIS-1101-1034-E1",                                "NULL=NULL",                            "NULL=NULL",
  "DIS-1101-1035-E1",                                "NULL=NULL",                            "NULL=NULL",
  "DIS-1101-1036-E1",                "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=89.00",            "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=18.60",
  "DIS-1101-1037-E1",                                "NULL=NULL",                            "NULL=NULL",
  "DIS-1101-1038-E1",               "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=101.00",             "BASELINE=4.30;FIRST=5.90",
  "DIS-1101-1039-E1",                             "FIRST=151.00",                           "FIRST=7.60",
  "DIS-1101-1040-E1",                             "FIRST=106.00",                           "FIRST=3.10",
  "DIS-1101-1041-E1",               "BASELINE=81.00;FIRST=87.00",           "BASELINE=10.10;FIRST=11.40",
  "DIS-1101-1042-E1",                 "FIRST=94.00;SECOND=85.00",             "FIRST=12.00;SECOND=21.30",
  "DIS-1101-1042-E2",                              "FIRST=85.00",                           "FIRST=9.80",
  "DIS-1101-1043-E1",               "FIRST=118.00;SECOND=116.00",              "FIRST=29.50;SECOND=4.80",
  "DIS-1101-1044-E1",               "FIRST=101.00;SECOND=103.00",               "FIRST=4.60;SECOND=9.90",
  "DIS-1101-1045-E1",                             "FIRST=114.00",                          "FIRST=18.90",
  "DIS-1101-1046-E1",               "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=129.00",           "BASELINE=15.00;FIRST=13.00",
  "DIS-1101-1047-E1",             "BASELINE=123.00;FIRST=105.00",           "BASELINE=12.80;FIRST=10.60",
  "DIS-1101-1048-E1",                                "NULL=NULL",                            "NULL=NULL",
  "DIS-1101-1049-E1",                                "NULL=NULL",                            "NULL=NULL"
  )

df |> 
  separate_rows(-UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID, sep = ";") |> 
  pivot_longer(-UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID) |> 
  separate(value, into = c("timepoint", "value"), sep = "=") |> 
  mutate(name = str_remove(name, ".*\\.")) |> 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c("name", "timepoint")) |> 
  select(UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID, sort(tidyselect::peek_vars()), -contains("NULL"))

#> # A tibble: 50 × 7
#>    UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID HAEMOGLOBIN_BASELINE HAEMOGLOBIN_FIRST HAEMOGLOBIN_SECOND
#>    <chr>             <chr>                <chr>             <chr>             
#>  1 DIS-1101-1001-E1  123.00               117.00            <NA>              
#>  2 DIS-1101-1002-E1  <NA>                 92.00             <NA>              
#>  3 DIS-1101-1003-E1  <NA>                 111.00            <NA>              
#>  4 DIS-1101-1004-E1  125.00               113.00            <NA>              
#>  5 DIS-1101-1004-E2  <NA>                 124.00            <NA>              
#>  6 DIS-1101-1005-E1  <NA>                 <NA>              <NA>              
#>  7 DIS-1101-1006-E1  <NA>                 <NA>              <NA>              
#>  8 DIS-1101-1007-E1  <NA>                 77.00             <NA>              
#>  9 DIS-1101-1008-E1  <NA>                 132.00            <NA>              
#> 10 DIS-1101-1009-E1  <NA>                 123.00            <NA>              
#> # … with 40 more rows, and 3 more variables: WHITE_CELLS_BASELINE <chr>,
#> #   WHITE_CELLS_FIRST <chr>, WHITE_CELLS_SECOND <chr>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

** UPDATE FOR YOUR WIDER SAMPLE2 DATASET **

To handle the varying number of separators across columns I've suggested a function to `separate_rows` iteratively by column. This overcomes the `separate_rows` error in the wider dataset that wasn't an issue in the sample dataset.

Using pattern matching, I've also extracted only strings referencing "BASELINE", "FIRST" or "SECOND" where these are associated with a value.

And as @harre notes, because some columns contain multiple, e.g. FIRSTs, I've subsequently taken the first of these using `slice_head` before using `pivot_wider`. You could instead take the last using `slice_tail` or take the mean etc. depending on the requirement.

You'll need to test further on your extended dataset, but hope this helps!

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- structure(list(UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID = c(
  "DIS-1104-1021-E1", "DIS-1107-1010-E1",
  "DIS-1124-1108-E1"
), `TIME_POINT_1=HAEMOGLOBIN` = c(
  "BASELINE=98.00;FIRST=90.00;SECOND=81.00;FIRST=85.00",
  "FIRST=120.00;NULL=120.00;NULL=118.00;SECOND=109.00;NULL=186.00",
  "BASELINE=78.00;FIRST=NULL;FIRST=99.00"
), `TIME_POINT_2=WHITE_CELLS` = c(
  "BASELINE=0.01;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=0.01;FIRST=0.00",
  "FIRST=15.40;NULL=16.10;NULL=14.50;SECOND=11.40;NULL=2.20;NULL=5.00",
  "BASELINE=85.00;FIRST=NULL;FIRST=209.00"
), `TIME_POINT_3=PLATELETS` = c(
  "BASELINE=28.00;FIRST=28.00;SECOND=12.00;FIRST=21.00",
  "FIRST=200.00;NULL=186.00;NULL=203.00;SECOND=243.00;NULL=145.00;NULL=457.00",
  "BASELINE=186.00;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_4=NEUTROPHILS` = c(
  "BASELINE=0.00;FIRST=0.00;SECOND=0.00",
  "FIRST=13.00;NULL=13.20;NULL=11.10;SECOND=7.70;NULL=1.30;NULL=2.20",
  "BASELINE=7.10;FIRST=2.40;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_5=LYMPHOCYTES` = c(
  "BASELINE=0.00;FIRST=0.00;SECOND=0.00",
  "FIRST=0.80;NULL=1.60;NULL=1.40;SECOND=1.70;NULL=0.40", "BASELINE=76.80;FIRST=135.00;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_6=MONOCYTES` = c(
  "BASELINE=0.00;FIRST=0.00;SECOND=0.00",
  "FIRST=1.50;NULL=1.20;NULL=1.90;SECOND=2.00;NULL=0.40;NULL=0.90",
  "BASELINE=1.40;FIRST=4.20;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_7=EOSINOPHILS` = c(
  "BASELINE=0.00;FIRST=0.00;SECOND=0.00",
  "FIRST=0.10;NULL=0.00;SECOND=0.00;NULL=0.10;NULL=0.30", "BASELINE=0.10;FIRST=0.40;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_8=FIBRINOGEN` = c(
  "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL",
  "FIRST=6.90;NULL=6.60;NULL=7.10;SECOND=6.60;NULL=6.00;NULL=NULL",
  "BASELINE=6.70;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_9=PT` = c(
  "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL",
  "FIRST=19.20;NULL=17.20;NULL=16.10;SECOND=14.40;NULL=14.90;NULL=NULL",
  "BASELINE=13.40;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_10=UREA` = c(
  "BASELINE=4.30;FIRST=4.30;SECOND=5.10;FIRST=4.50",
  "FIRST=3.80;NULL=3.70;NULL=4.40;SECOND=2.80;NULL=2.90;NULL=4.10",
  "BASELINE=5.10;FIRST=NULL;FIRST=7.20"
), `TIME_POINT_11=CREATININE` = c(
  "BASELINE=67.00;FIRST=55.00;SECOND=61.00;FIRST=60.00",
  "FIRST=44.00;NULL=42.00;NULL=45.00;SECOND=42.00;NULL=33.00",
  "BASELINE=65.00;FIRST=NULL;FIRST=72.00"
), `TIME_POINT_12=ALT` = c(
  "BASELINE=9.00;FIRST=11.00;SECOND=8.00;FIRST=5.00",
  "FIRST=20.00;NULL=NULL;NULL=19.00;SECOND=16.00;NULL=16.00;NULL=21.00",
  "BASELINE=64.00;FIRST=NULL;FIRST=92.00"
), `TIME_POINT_13=BILIRUBIN` = c(
  "BASELINE=3.00;FIRST=5.00;SECOND=3.00;FIRST=NULL",
  "FIRST=20.00;NULL=NULL;NULL=11.00;SECOND=10.00;NULL=5.00", "BASELINE=7.00;FIRST=NULL;FIRST=10.00"
), `TIME_POINT_14=ALBUMIN` = c(
  "BASELINE=42.00;FIRST=39.00;SECOND=35.00;FIRST=36.00",
  "FIRST=42.00;NULL=NULL;NULL=37.00;SECOND=35.00;NULL=35.00;NULL=39.00",
  "BASELINE=31.00;FIRST=NULL;FIRST=40.00"
), `TIME_POINT_15=VITAMIN_D` = c(
  "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL",
  "FIRST=NULL;NULL=NULL;SECOND=NULL", "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_16=CRP` = c(
  "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=172.00;SECOND=116.00;FIRST=212.00",
  "FIRST=427.00;NULL=420.00;NULL=338.00;SECOND=215.00;NULL=87.00;NULL=64.00",
  "BASELINE=199.00;FIRST=NULL;FIRST=1.00"
), `TIME_POINT_17=PCT` = c(
  "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL",
  "FIRST=NULL;NULL=NULL;SECOND=NULL", "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_18=FERRITIN` = c(
  "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL",
  "FIRST=NULL;NULL=NULL;NULL=378.00;SECOND=NULL", "BASELINE=809.00;FIRST=432.00;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_19=TROP_T` = c(
  "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL",
  "FIRST=NULL;NULL=NULL;NULL=3.00;SECOND=NULL", "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_20=D_DIMER` = c(
  "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL",
  "FIRST=NULL;NULL=1.85;NULL=1.65;SECOND=NULL;NULL=NULL", "BASELINE=749.00;FIRST=486.00;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_21=INR` = c(
  "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL",
  "FIRST=NULL;NULL=NULL;SECOND=NULL", "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_22=BNP_NT` = c(
  "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL",
  "FIRST=NULL;NULL=NULL;SECOND=NULL", "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_23=LDH` = c(
  "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL",
  "FIRST=NULL;NULL=NULL;SECOND=NULL", "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=254.00;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_24=CK` = c(
  "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL",
  "FIRST=NULL;NULL=NULL;NULL=29.00;SECOND=NULL", "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_25=SCD_25` = c(
  "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL",
  "FIRST=NULL;NULL=NULL;SECOND=NULL", "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_26=BASE_EXCESS` = c(
  "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL",
  "FIRST=3.10;NULL=1.50;NULL=NULL;SECOND=NULL", "BASELINE=-3.80;FIRST=NULL"
), `TIME_POINT_27=LACTATE` = c(
  "BASELINE=NULL;FIRST=NULL;SECOND=NULL",
  "FIRST=0.90;NULL=1.30;NULL=NULL;SECOND=NULL", "BASELINE=0.60;FIRST=NULL"
)), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))



pattern <- c("FIRST=\\d{2,3}.\\d{0,2}|SECOND=\\d{2,3}.\\d{0,2}|BASELINE=\\d{2,3}.\\d{0,2}")

# Function to iteratively separate by column
separate_iteratively <- function(col){
  separate_rows(df2, col, sep = ";") |> 
    select(1, col)
}

# Extract only if BASELINE, FIRST or SECOND with an associate number
df2 <- df |> 
  mutate(across(-UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID, ~ str_extract_all(., pattern) |> 
                  map_chr(~str_c(., collapse = ";"))))

# Separate & rearrange
df3 <- map_dfr(2:ncol(df2), separate_iteratively) |> 
  pivot_longer(-UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID) |> 
  filter(!is.na(value) & !value == "") |> 
  separate(value, into = c("timepoint", "value"), sep = "=") |> 
  mutate(name = str_remove(name, ".*=")) |> 
  arrange(UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID, name, timepoint) |> 
  group_by(UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID, name, timepoint) |> 
  slice_head(n = 1) |> # Or use slice_tail
  pivot_wider(names_from = c("name", "timepoint"))|> 
  select(UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID, sort(tidyselect::peek_vars()))

df3
#> # A tibble: 3 × 35
#> # Groups:   UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID [3]
#>   UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID ALBUMIN_BASELINE ALBUMIN_FIRST ALBUMIN_SECOND ALT_BASELINE
#>   <chr>             <chr>            <chr>         <chr>          <chr>       
#> 1 DIS-1104-1021-E1  42.00            39.00         35.00          <NA>        
#> 2 DIS-1107-1010-E1  <NA>             42.00         35.00          <NA>        
#> 3 DIS-1124-1108-E1  31.00            40.00         <NA>           64.00       
#> # … with 30 more variables: ALT_FIRST <chr>, ALT_SECOND <chr>,
#> #   BILIRUBIN_FIRST <chr>, BILIRUBIN_SECOND <chr>, CREATININE_BASELINE <chr>,
#> #   CREATININE_FIRST <chr>, CREATININE_SECOND <chr>, CRP_BASELINE <chr>,
#> #   CRP_FIRST <chr>, CRP_SECOND <chr>, D_DIMER_BASELINE <chr>,
#> #   D_DIMER_FIRST <chr>, FERRITIN_BASELINE <chr>, FERRITIN_FIRST <chr>,
#> #   HAEMOGLOBIN_BASELINE <chr>, HAEMOGLOBIN_FIRST <chr>,
#> #   HAEMOGLOBIN_SECOND <chr>, LDH_FIRST <chr>, LYMPHOCYTES_BASELINE <chr>, …


# Just to illustrate the issue with varying separators
tribble(~v1, ~v2,
        "a;a", "b;b",
        "a;a", "b;b;b",
        ) |> 
  separate_rows(everything(), sep = ";")
#> Error in `fn()`:
#> ! In row 2, can't recycle input of size 2 to size 3.

# Works
tribble(~v1, ~v2,
        "a;a", "b;b",
        "a;a", "b;b",
) |> 
  separate_rows(everything(), sep = ";")
#> # A tibble: 4 × 2
#>   v1    v2   
#>   <chr> <chr>
#> 1 a     b    
#> 2 a     b    
#> 3 a     b    
#> 4 a     b
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Typo in the mutate, need to be: `str_remove(name, ".*=")`

Comment: Nope. It's removing "TIME_POINT_1." etc.

Comment: Didn't see the change of column name. For OP the colname is `TIME_POINT_1=HAEMOGLOBIN`, not `TIME_POINT_1.HAEMOGLOBIN`.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean @Harre .  The "=" what converted to the more syntactic "." when I created the example input `tribble`. I've shown both above.

Comment: @Carl Thank you! It works, however when I apply the code to 27 blood tests and 2500 samples I get an error. I've updated my question with some entries that are throwing the error. I'd appreciate you taking a look please. I think it may be to do with some NULL values?

Comment: @lecb the problem seems to be that each row has a varying number of separators, i.e. `;`s across the columns which was not the case for the sample dataset. If I get chance a little later I'll see if there is a neat workaround. Presume the NULLs are needed?

Comment: @Carl Ahh I see. Thank you so much. I think we could dispense of the NULLs if that makes it easier?

Comment: Your problem is rather that some values are not unique. See for instance: `BASELINE=98.00;FIRST=90.00;SECOND=81.00;FIRST=85.00`. You need to decide which "FIRST" value to keep. In order to see this in an appropriate format: flip the `pivot_longer` and `separate_rows`.

Comment: I've added an update to 1) overcome the `separate_rows` issue due to the varying number of separators across columns in the more complex sample2 dataset and 2) address the subsequent `pivot_wider` issue noted by @harre given the sample2 dataset has multiple FIRSTs etc. I've take the first FIRST, but you could take the last or mean etc. per the notes above.

Answer (score 1):

Building on my comments above and @Carl's implementation, you you could utilize the nested list structure directly using `values_fn`, which might save you from some lines of code. I am using `first()` from `dplyr` to take the first element, but you could as well use other functions depending on what you prefer, `~ mean(as.numeric(.))` to take the mean etc. There is no varying number of separators when we `pivot_longer` before using `separate_rows`, when I run the data.

```r
df |> 
    pivot_longer(-UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID) |> 
    separate_rows(-UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID, sep = ";") |> 
    separate(value, into = c("timepoint", "value"), sep = "=") |> 
    mutate(name = str_remove(name, ".*=")) |>
    filter(!is.na(value) & value != "NULL" & timepoint != "NULL") |>
    pivot_wider(names_from = c("name", "timepoint"), values_fn = ~ first(.)) |>
    select(UNIQUE_PATIENT_ID, sort(tidyselect::peek_vars()))
```